# DSE cassandra not starting

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

faced with a problem, we have cluster of 5 nodes after restart dse trying to start without success the last record in system.log is below...
Tried with heap and 48 and 64, node has 128GB. Three of them started but these two cannot, no error in the log just that record.

> INFO  [main] 2017-05-16 21:16:27,507  CassandraDaemon.java:487 - JVM Arguments: [-Ddse.server_process, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Dcassandra.disable_auth_caches_remote_configuration=false, -Dcassandra.force_default_indexing_page_size=false, -Dcassandra.join_ring=true, -Dcassandra.load_ring_state=true, -Dcassandra.write_survey=false, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -ea, -XX:G1RSetUpdatingPauseTimePercent=5, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xms16G, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500, -Xmx16G, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -Xss256k, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/etc/dse/cassandra/hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/dse/hadoop2-client/lib/native:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin:/usr/share/dse/hadoop2-client/lib/native:/usr/share/dse/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin:, -Dguice_include_stack_traces=OFF, -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=128658, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader, -Dguice_include_stack_traces=OFF, -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=128658, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config.DseConfigurationLoader, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/var/log/cassandra, -Dcassandra.storagedir=/usr/share/dse/data, -Dcassandra-pidfile=/var/run/dse/dse.pid, -Dgraph-enabled=true, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/lib/cassandra/java_1494958565.hprof, -XX:ErrorFile=/var/lib/cassandra/hs_err_1494958565.log, -Dguice_include_stack_traces=OFF, -Ddse.system_memory_in_mb=128658, -Dcassandra.config.loader=com.datastax.bdp.config

Comment: Is there any Error log ??

Comment: Just Found only in messages
May 17 01:21:40 cass-node5 kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 12701 (java) score 962 or sacrifice child
May 17 01:21:40 cass-node5 kernel: Killed process 12701 (java) total-vm:182601672kB, anon-rss:71079584kB, file-rss:58766836kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[root@cass-node5 ~]#

Comment: vm:182601672kB - this is all db on this node.

Comment: http://grokbase.com/t/cassandra/user/152a16papp/out-of-memory-error-while-opening-sstables-on-startup

so this is my case?

Comment: The OOM killer is getting your app. This means that the OS overcommitted ram to make your JVM. Then when it needed ram to do something for real it had to get some ram back, so it killed your server. Ironically making the JVM smaller will avoid the OOM killer.

Comment: Thank you! so you mean decrease -Xms16G to 8Gb?